# Angular Reactive Forms pattern validation: Invalid regular expression

Tags: regex, angular, validation

I have a regex for Australia phone number validation working in an AngularJS website. I have set the exact pattern in the Reactive Forms validator as follows:

```
 Validators.pattern(
  '/^({0,1}((0|+61)(2|4|3|7|8))){0,1}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{3}$/'
 )
```

The page doesn't load as it gets the following error:

> Invalid regular expression: /^/^({0,1}((0|+61)(2|4|3|7|8))){0,1}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{3}$/$/: Nothing to repeat

What is the correct way to specify this pattern when using Reactive Forms?

Comment: `^({0,1}...`: the  `{0,1}` quantifier repeats nothing. You should read a regex tutorial, in particular about quantifiers and character classes (to avoid useless alternations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

- The regex literal should not be used inside quotes (or use a string pattern with double escaped special chars)
- Special chars like `(`, `)` and `+` must be escaped - *nothing to repeat* is caused by the fact that `(` (start of a capturing group) is quantified with `{0,1}` and that is an error
- `{0,1}` is equal to `?`, `( |-)` can be written as `[ -]`, `(2|4|3|7|8)` canbe written shorter as `[23478]`.

So, you may use

```
Validators.pattern(
  '^\\(?(0|\\+61)[24378]\\)?[ -]?[0-9]{2}[ -]?[0-9]{2}[ -]?[0-9][ -]?[0-9]{3}$'
)
```

Note that you may even omit `^` and `$` here since the anchors will be added by Angular automatically to the string pattern.

*NOTE*: if the separators should be consistent, capture the first one and then use backreferences to the group value:

```
Validators.pattern(
  '\\(?(?:0|\\+61)[24378]\\)?([ -]?)[0-9]{2}\\1[0-9]{2}\\1[0-9]\\1[0-9]{3}'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass pattern as string, without / which are the delimiters for regex

`Validators.pattern('^({0,1}((0|+61)(2|4|3|7|8))){0,1}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{3}$/')`

Comment: Why do I need a custom validator when there is a built-in pattern validator that should do the job?

Comment: @Anthony I updated my answer, can you give it a shot and let me know, I'n curious if that would solve the issue.

Comment: With the updated answer I get - SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^^({0,1}((0|+61)(2|4|3|7|8))){0,1}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}( |-){0,1}[0-9]{3}$/$/: Nothing to repeat
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)