# Validate telephone number in Angular

Tags: regex, angular

I am trying to validate telephone numbers in my Angular application. I have a form with a n input field. I am trying the following but am getting the below error.

> Invalid regular expression: /^(?:+?(61))? ?(?:((?=.*)))?(0?[2-57-8]))?
>   ?(dd(?:- |(?!dd[- ]?d[- ]))dd[- ]?d[- ]?d{3})$/: Nothing to
>   repeat

HTML

```
<div class="input-container">
<label for="mobile">Cell number*</label>
<input id="mobile" type="text" formControlName="mobile" size="10" placeholder="000 000 000">
</div>
<p class="error"*ngIf="!userFormGroup.get('mobile').valid && userFormGroup.get('mobile').dirty">
   * Invalid mobile number.
</p>
```

TS

```
mobile: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?:\+?(61))? ?(?:\((?=.*\)))?(0?[2-57-8])\)? ?(\d\d(?:[- ](?=\d{3})|(?!\d\d[- ]?\d[- ]))\d\d[- ]?\d[- ]?\d{3})$')])
```

I basically need to validate that the input has a minimum of 10 digits, allows for the + characters, excludes any white spaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this condition `userFormGroup.get('mobile').hasError('pattern')`

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mobile-validation-reactive-form?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts)

RegEx

```
Validators.pattern('(([+][(]?[0-9]{1,3}[)]?)|([(]?[0-9]{4}[)]?))\s*[)]?[-\s\.]?[(]?[0-9]{1,3}[)]?([-\s\.]?[0-9]{3})([-\s\.]?[0-9]{3,4})')
```

Template

```
<p class="error" *ngIf="userFormGroup.get('mobile').invalid && (userFormGroup.get('mobile').dirty || userFormGroup.get('mobile').touched)">
    <ng-container *ngIf="userFormGroup.get('mobile').hasError('required')">
        mobile is Required!
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="userFormGroup.get('mobile').hasError('pattern')">
        * Invalid mobile number.
    </ng-container>
</p>
```

Comment: I think the regular expression I am using is not correct as the error I get in the console is `Invalid regular expression: /^(?:+?(61))? ?(?:((?=.*)))?(0?[2-57-8]))? ?(dd(?:[- ](?=d{3})|(?!dd[- ]?d[- ]))dd[- ]?d[- ]?d{3})$/: Nothing to repeat`

Comment: you can use `^(\\+?\d{1,4}[\s-])?(?!0+\s+,?$)\\d{10}\s*,?$` pattern for mobile validation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493985/angular-reactive-forms-pattern-validation-invalid-regular-expression

Comment: This does not seem to allow the + character before the number so international numbers can't be inserted

Comment: try with this RegEx - `(([+][(]?[0-9]{1,3}[)]?)|([(]?[0-9]{4}[)]?))\s*[)]?[-\s\.]?[(]?[0-9]{1,3}[)]?([-\s\.]?[0-9]{3})([-\s\.]?[0-9]{3,4})`

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
<span class="warning" *ngIf="userFormGroup.controls['mobile'].errors?.pattern">
    * *Please insert a valid phone number</span>
```

Phone number [regular expression](https://regexr.com/3c53v) `^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. This may help you to fix the issue.

**HTML**

```
<form>
 <div [formGroup]="userFormGroup">
  <label for="mobile">
  Mobile:
  <input id="mobile" type="number" formControlName="mobile" placeholder="1 000 000 000" required>
  </label>
  <p class="error"*ngIf="!userFormGroup.get('mobile').valid && userFormGroup.get('mobile').dirty">
     * Invalid mobile number.
  </p>
 </div>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent  {
name = 'Angular';

userFormGroup = new FormGroup({
 mobile: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(\\+?\d{1,4}[\s-])?(?!0+\s+,?$)\\d{10}\s*,?$')] ),
 });
}
```

> [StackBlitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mobile-number-validator-pattern)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This regex pattern will accept most of the phone numbers

```
^([+-]{0,1}[ ]{0,1}[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[ ]{0,1}){0,4}$
```